# could not find sqlite3.dylib after updating xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c

I could not find `sqlite3.dylib` after updating `xcode 7.3`. Instead I am getting as `sqlite3.tbd`.

I have searched solutions for this and have followed procedures like:

1. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
3. From /usr/lib you can add : libz.dylib and more...

But when I'm searching for `/usr/lib`, it shows the folder can't be found .

Anyone has anymore solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use sqlite3.tbd it is same as sqlite3.dylib.**

Comment: no . it wont work same as before . suppose you add sqlite.tbd file . but it contains only texts . after that , when you will try to import#import<sqlite3.h>

Comment: What you want to save in the database ?

Comment: it automatically works now .. even showing the path from where sqlite3.h file imports . great , sqlite3.tbd works .

Comment: A wild guess is that using sqlite in the application try to delete the previous application from simulator before if you change any thing related DB configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The actual file is here:

```
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

For future reference, if you're in need of searching for something like that, drop to terminal and the `locate libsqlite3.dylib`

You should end up with an output which shows you where found locations of the file are e.g.:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

in my case

Comment: if the `libsqlite3.dylib` is in `/usr/lib` then you probably need to update the locate database by running `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. It's pretty resource intensive, but once it's done, locate will work nicely